# How to call oracle plsql script(.sql) in java program

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

I have one .sql script and want to execute it from a java program using jdbc driver(oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver").

Please guide me how can i execute iniside java program.

---

### EDIT (copied from OP's comment)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.lang.*;

public class OracleConnection
  { public static void main(String[] args)
        throws Exception
      {
      Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
      SqlScript.execute("/home/hyperion/Oracle/Middleware/EPMSystem11R1/products/Found‌​ation/server/conf/create_oracle_cms.sql");
      }
  }
```

I want to execute the script in the last line.

---

Comment: This may help you http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B25329_01/doc/appdev.102/b25108/xedev_jdbc.htm

Comment: Compile your program and call it with CallableStatement directly from your database.

Comment: Can you provide an example to call a script something like /ap01/oracle/test.sql in java

Comment: import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.lang.*;

public class OracleConnection {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        SqlScript.execute("/home/hyperion/Oracle/Middleware/EPMSystem11R1/products/Foundation/server/conf/create_oracle_cms.sql");
    }
}
I want to execute the script in the last line. Please help me

Comment: @navi27 add this code to your post. Don't forget to format it(select the code and press for windows CTRL+K)

Comment: If the script has multiple statements then you'd have to parse each statement out, which isn't trivial depending on the types of statement involved, and execute each one individually. Something called `create_oracle_cms.sql` is likely to have various types of statements I'd have thought. Why would you want to run a one-off script from Java?

Comment: i'm very new to java. Can some one provide me sample code to call an sql script and execute it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register your driver first:

```
Class.forName(yourDriverClassName);
```